# How can I generate CMYK images via the command line under Linux?

Tags: command-line, image-manipulation, color-management

I have an application I have developed which is generating RGB PNG images with text on them via imageMagic, like so:

```
convert -size 1000x1000 -density 300 xc:white -pointsize 24 \
  -fill "rgb(0,0,0)" -annotate +500+500 'Josh Test' Jtest.png
```

It's working great. However I need to be able to generate CMYK output as well, the same images, but in CMYK rather than RGB. InkScape can't do this. I thought I could just use a CMYK color:

```
convert -colorspace cmyk -density 300 xc:white -pointsize 24 \
  -fill "cmyk(0,0,0,0)" -annotate +500+500 'Josh Test' Jtest.pdf
```

However the resulting image is not 100% black, but 100% cyan, 100% magenta, 100% yellow and 0% black. Actual colors look even worse. This is because [ImageMagic does all drawing in an RGB space and converts to CMYK](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10784):

> Drawing requires the RGBA color model. Internally, images are stored as RGB(A) or CMY(A)K.

I cannot generate RGB images and convert to CMYK, the colors won't be right. They must be CMYK the whole way through. How can I generate CMYK images under linux?

Answer (score 3):

Save a python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import sys

im = Image.new('CMYK', (1000,1000), (0, 0, 0, 255))

f = ImageFont.load_default()
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
d.text((500, 500), sys.argv[1], font = f, fill = (0, 0, 0, 0))
del d

im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Dependencies are python and the python imaging library. Then you can create your images with this command:

```
python cmyktext.py "Josh test" Jtest.pdf
```

Don't forget that cmyk is subtractive, so (0,0,0,0) is actually white. It is of course also possible to use any font you like, as documented [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagefont.htm).

Comment: Woah, if this works it will be awesome as I have one customer begging me to support CMYK. I'll test this soon. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I hope it works for you!